# 'npm start' is stuck on 'Starting the development server ...' after create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npm-start

I am starting to learn react. And following the tutorials, the first thing I do is create a react app using 'create-react-app'.

Though, it gave me a few high-severity vulnerabilities pasted below-

```
Creating a new React app in /Users/girishtiwale/Dropbox/#Girish/My_Workspace/react_practice/new-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


added 1393 packages in 31s

203 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
npm notice 
npm notice New patch version of npm available! 8.15.0 -> 8.15.1
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.15.1
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@8.15.1 to update!
npm notice 

Initialized a git repository.

Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated

added 52 packages in 4s

203 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
npm notice 
npm notice New patch version of npm available! 8.15.0 -> 8.15.1
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.15.1
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@8.15.1 to update!
npm notice 
Removing template package using npm...


removed 1 package, and audited 1445 packages in 1s

203 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
npm notice 
npm notice New patch version of npm available! 8.15.0 -> 8.15.1
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.15.1
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@8.15.1 to update!
npm notice 

Created git commit.

Success! Created new-app at /Users/girishtiwale/Dropbox/#Girish/My_Workspace/react_practice/new-app
Inside that directory, you can run several commands:

  npm start
    Starts the development server.

  npm run build
    Bundles the app into static files for production.

  npm test
    Starts the test runner.

  npm run eject
    Removes this tool and copies build dependencies, configuration files
    and scripts into the app directory. If you do this, you can’t go back!

We suggest that you begin by typing:

  cd new-app
  npm start

Happy hacking!
npm notice 
npm notice New patch version of npm available! 8.15.0 -> 8.15.1
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.15.1
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@8.15.1 to update!
npm notice
```

But when I don 'npm start', the console displays 'Starting the development server ...', it opens a browser tab with localhost:3000 automatically, and then nothing happens...

[Here is a Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v77S6.png)

Answer (score 0):

wait till the end of process started. Take some time. Two ways could be later - error or happy start. In case of error share the error first. Check the console

Comment: Okay, will wait till the process ends

Comment: this process is still running. neither any error nor a happy start.

Comment: @girishmt4 share the file system. Is there any js files in it? Is there index.js does index.js has React code inside?

Comment: @girishmt4 can you open developer tools in browser and then open localhost:3000 what is happening on console and network?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `npx create-react-app <name-of-your-app>` to create the app?

If so maybe use `npm run start` to start your application it should be located in your **package.json** section example is:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

so in this case you would run `npm run "dev"` as `npm run dev`

Comment: It behaves exactly the same way as before, getting stuck after 'Starting the development server ...'

Comment: hmm interesting... 

1. Have you checked if there's enough storage on your HDD or SSD?
2. Run `npm install -g npm@8.15.1` to update your npm
3. maybe your not in the parent directory

Comment: Yes, I do have more than enough space on my SSD. Even after updating the npm globally, the same result

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to go inside the folder before 'npm start'.

As it says, you have to:

```
cd new-app
npm start
```

Comment: I did go inside the folder and then ran the command 'npm start'...

Comment: Maybe `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: Tried this too. Still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

can you tell us what is written in your scripts in package.json
this should be something like this

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

and what is your node version?

Comment: Yes my scripts object is exactly the same

Comment: my node version 16.14.0

Answer (score 0):

Ok, remove your node module and install it again with npm install
then try again if this didn't work first add npm build then npm install

Answer (score 0):

have you tried running "npm dev" before "npm start"?
also you can try running "npm start -p 3030" to run it on a different localhost server.

Comment: Please do not post comments as answers

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."